# Python: Using two function returns simultaneously

Tags: python

I'm searching for a (probably obvious) way of reducing the time my code takes to run.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

l = 4000000

def my_func(n):
    m = 3 * n
    z = n**2
    return(m,z)

am = []
az = []

for i in range(l): # question is referring to this loop
   am.append(my_func(i)[0])
   az.append(my_func(i)[1])

x = range(l)
plt.plot(x, am)
plt.plot(x, az)
plt.show()
```

In the i-loop `my_func` always runs twice and discards one of the two returned values, which sounds super inefficient to me. So how can I fill my `am` array with the first and my `az` array with the second values `my_func` returns, without running it twice for every i and only using half the returns every time?

Comment: Unpacking the results in advance seems sufficient.

Comment: How much of the time is spent on building the list and how much on plotting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack the tuple returned from this function:

```
for i in range(l):
    m, z = my_func(i)
    am.append(m)
    az.append(z)
```

[This blog post](https://blog.teclado.com/destructuring-in-python/) nicely explains this concept in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to assign a variable to the return value of your function.

```
result = my_func(i)
am.append(result[0])
az.append(result[1])
```

Better yet, just unpack the result.

```
m, z = my_func(i)
am.append(m)
az.append(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do without a separate function altogether and append the two arrays as

```
am.append(3*i)
az.append(i**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the values:

```
m, z = my_func(i)
am.append(m)
az.append(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   am.append(my_func(i)[0])
   az.append(my_func(i)[1])
```

You can change to

```
   tup = my_func(i)
   am.append(tup[0])
   az.append(tup[1])
```

Then again, you don't need to call the function over here. You can easily do one thing.

```
x = np.arange(l)
plt.plot(x, 3*x)
plt.plot(x, x*x)
plt.show()
```

##### Timing

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
start_time = time.time()

l = 4000000

def my_func(n):
    m = 3 * n
    z = n**2
    return(m,z)

am = []
az = []

for i in range(l): # question is referring to this loop
   am.append(my_func(i)[0])
   az.append(my_func(i)[1])

x = range(l)
plt.plot(x, am)
plt.plot(x, az)
plt.show()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

##### Output:

[image]

##### Code-2

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
start_time = time.time()

l = 4000000

# def my_func(n):
#     m = 3 * n
#     z = n**2
#     return(m,z)

# am = []
# az = []

# for i in range(l): # question is referring to this loop
#    am.append(my_func(i)[0])
#    az.append(my_func(i)[1])

x = np.arange(l)
plt.plot(x, 3*x)
plt.plot(x, x*x)
plt.show()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

##### Output

[image]

Instead of using for loop, you can simply use vectorization to speed up the operation, as shown in the pictures( 5-6 times faster roughly). Also try to not call the same function multiple times to reuse the same value. Better to call it once and store the result.

Comment: @MechanicPig Ah yes. I was adding something else. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although you're right timing-wise my_func is just a dummy function I put in order to ask the question, the actual function does a lot more, but in the end just returns two values, hence the dummy function, which I can't eliminate completely as you did in the last version. Unpacking worked, as many before have suggested tho!

Comment: @Tim.: Most likely not possible to answer in this scope, but usually you can almost always avoid for loop. That is the message. Even if your function is doing a lot of thing, you can (almost) always vectorize it.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the value in a variable :

```
results = my_func(i)
am.append(results[0])
az.append(results[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `np.vectorize`

```py
am, az = np.vectorize(my_func)(range(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the below? Save the returned tuple and append to the lists.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

l = 4000000

def my_func(n):
    m = 3 * n
    z = n**2
    return(m,z)

am = []
az = []

for i in range(l): # question is referring to this loop
    m, z = my_func(i)
    am.append(m)
    az.append(z)

x = range(l)
plt.plot(x, am)
plt.plot(x, az)
plt.show()
```